# How do I move a window's position on the computer screen with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, methods, window

I remember seeing a google maps mashup / music video that created, resized, and moved windows on the screen. What javascript methods are used to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know how reliable this is, but to move the window relative to it's current position you can do this:

```
window.moveBy(250, 250); //moves 250px to the left and 250px down
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_moveby.asp

To move the window to a certain part of the screen:

```
window.moveTo(0, 0); //moves to the top left corner of the screen (primary)
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_moveto.asp

Courtesy of @Dan Herbert:

> It should probably be noted that `window.moveTo(0,0)` will move to the
>   top left corner of the primary screen. For people with multiple
>   monitors you can also send negative coordinates to position on another
>   monitor. You can check for a second monitor to move to with
>   `screen.availLeft`. If it's negative, you can move a window that far
>   onto the second monitor.

Comment: It should probably be noted that `window.moveTo(0,0)` will move to the top left corner of the _primary_ screen. For people with multiple monitors you can also send negative coordinates to position on another monitor. You can check for a second monitor to move to with `screen.availLeft`. If it's negative, you can move a window that far onto the second monitor.

Comment: Excellent remark. I'm going to include your comments in my answer.

Comment: @DanHerbert Note that screen.availLeft does not work for IE browsers.

Answer (score 1):

From a quick google search: [Moving windows](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/advwin2.shtml)

You're looking for Window.moveBy and window.moveTo

I remember that video too, you select your hometown and whatnot?  I quite liked that.

Answer (score 0):

You move a displayed object's position by changing its top and left margins, which, together, are the coordinates of its top left corner. If you know the absolute coordinates of the target position, you can change the margins and the object will move to that spot.

If you don't know the absolute target position, but only know two relative deltas (i.e., move the window up 5 pixels and right 10 pixels), you can read the object's top and left margins, increment those by the appropriate distances, and set the margins from that.

Margins are part of the style of the object, so you'd say something like:

```
  theobject.style.left = 10 + 'px'; 
  theobject.style.top  = 40 + 'px';
```

for a positioned object.

Comment: I think you might misunderstand me. I'm not talking about elements on the page. I'm talking about the browser window itself.

Answer (score 0):

Since your links contain anchors, "#", when you click on the links it will move the page back to the top. Try replacing the href with something like:

```
href="javascript:void(0)"
```

This will prevent anything within the href from executing.