# Is it possible to move a newly open window to another monitor?

Tags: javascript, browser

Let's say you open a new window on your right (primary) monitor like so:

`foo = window.open('test.htm','testFoo','width=700,height=225');`

And you want to move it to your second monitor on the left side like so:

`foo.moveBy(-470);`

This works up until it hits the left edge of the right monitor, after that, it just stays stuck there. I haven't been able to find any JS to allow me to make the "jump" between monitors.

I've made a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/2NGyN/

EDIT: Assume the monitor layout is known. Not that it would make a difference because the crux of the problem is that as far as I can tell, you can not move a window into another monitor with javascript.

Comment: im afraid that its not possible to know the monitor layout.

Comment: Well the question assumes a known monitor layout...

Comment: What Daniel is saying is that js doesn't have a knowledge of the monitor layout. It's not something available to the api.

Comment: There's a few older answers that seem to have implied it possible to "jump" between monitors in the past, regardless of layout. Here's one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841849/how-do-i-move-a-windows-position-on-the-computer-screen-with-javascript

Comment: Your desktop manager is responsible for that behaviour. I don't think it's accessible from JS, so you cannot workaround that. Try to configure your OS so that is has only one desktop that stretches across all monitors.

Comment: The only thing you can do to accomplish this, is assume they are opening the main browser on the left monitor. If you open the window, and set "left" = 9999999;, it will position the window in the farthest right monitor. Though, this is a hack way of doing it, and isn't stable. You cannot get the current monitor layout as mentioned earlier, but can force the window to open farthest left, or farthest to the right.                                    

 windowObjectReference = window.open(
   "http://www.google.com",
   "width=420,height=230,resizable,scrollbars=yes,status=1, left=9999999"
 );

Comment: Here is a good resource that speaks about this. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/7b680e09-0145-4f5e-97ca-158fa563f7ae/how-can-i-detect-whether-there-are-dual-monitors-connected-to-the-computer-by-using-javascript?forum=iewebdevelopment

Comment: @Casey: I tried that in the fiddle and still same problem, it won't break away the monitor it started from. This really has nothing to do with monitor layout, even knowing the exact monitor layout I can not get a window across two monitors with JS.

Comment: @Alex. I tried it on my system, and worked. I am sorry I cannot further help, as I am not sure then how to come up with a stable solution. I apologize for this.

Comment: No need for apologies, but I am really curious. What browser were you using and hows your system set up?

Answer (score 0):

Found a article that explains ho you can do this in c#, then translate to javascript.  Assuming it is that important, that you will what to handle it this way.  Hopefully this helps.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/ef62fcb7-f7a4-4537-8cd1-5a7ac433bcc9/howto-detect-and-manage-multiple-monitors-with-c-activex-or-netcontrol-that-is-then-used-by?forum=ieextensiondevelopment