# Reposition popup window with js userscript

Tags: javascript, window, tampermonkey, userscripts

I am the user of a web application for which I have no access to or control over the source code. The application contains a button which opens a new browser window with a specific title using javascript. The particular behavior of the javascript is (annoyingly) to always open the new window centered over the old window; I always immediately move it to my other monitor so I can view both windows at once.

I thought I would write a tampermonkey script that would automatically reposition the new window whenever I open it. Here is what I tried:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Example - reposition popup
// @namespace    
// @version      0.1
// @description  reposition the popup window that appears when [Image] button is clicked
// @author       Thecommexokid
// @match        https://example.com/pdfViewer.html*
// @icon         https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=openuserjs.org
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    window.moveBy(-968, -426);
    alert("Hello World");  // for testing
})();
```

The alert triggers, so I know the script runs, targets the correct window, etc. But the `moveBy` command has no visible effect.

I see there are a couple of restrictions listed in the documentation of the `moveBy` function:

> 1. You can't move a window or tab that wasn't created by `window.open()`.
> 2. You can't move a window or tab when it's in a window with more than one tab.

But the window in question is a standalone, unmaximized window; and investigating the webapp's js code with the web inspector, it was in fact created with `window.open`. (Not by *me*, admittedly.)

What's going wrong? Can this approach be salvaged? And is there a better approach to accomplish my actual goal of repositioning the popup window every time I open it?

Comment: Does the browser have an issue with you moving it off the screen? If you set it to like 10, 10, does it move it?

Comment: You seem to be onto something there. I can move the window to the edge of the current monitor (well, near the edge, it seems to be unwilling to go the last 3 or 4 pixels) but not across the boundary between monitors.

Comment: does moveTo() make any difference?

Comment: Old days you could move the browser off the window and you could not close it, It is probably not allowing it because of that. The good ole days of programming.

Comment: I just tried using `moveTo` per https://stackoverflow.com/a/7841872/1187304 but contrary to that answer, I didn't find that it allowed me to go beyond the edge of the primary monitor either. :(

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a [known limitation](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=234132) of Chrome that `moveTo` and `moveBy` are limited to the coordinates of the current screen. Quoting from the linked bug:

> Chrome currently clamps window.open() and window.moveTo|By to keep windows on the same screen as the original or originator.
> Chrome's window coordinates are relative to the primary display's origin; open/move coordinates should be offset by the relevant screen's top/left.
> The web platform doesn't yet expose information about screens other than the one hosting a given window.

A new [Window Placement API](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=897300) for Chrome is supposedly under development that would include this functionality.

Some users in the Chrome bug also claim that the desired functionality can be achieved currently in Firefox; I haven't checked this personally.